# SPI Interface linux

Tags: linux, spi

Micro controller is connected to Ethernet controller through SPI interface. Ethernet controller always gets configuration information from EEPROM(128) when board boots up. I have written basic driver to read/write eeprom, used data, control and status register to do read write opperation. This registers are memory mapped to process address space. Selecting eeprom by making chip select through GPIO.

Question: In the above scenario, what is the need SPI driver to read/write EEPROM. This register read operation is using SPI driver internally..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by you "Micro controller is connected to Ethernet controller through SPI interface. Ethernet controller always gets configuration information from EEPROM(128) when board boots up."

It means that the ethernet is tied to SPI bus. It cannot read/write data on it's own.It means eeprom is not using SPI but Ethernet controller is using it.Since it is reading/writing from/to EEPROM and hence it might be giving illusion that EEPROM is using SPI.

Note:- I am assuming EEPROM is not tied to SPI.